# How to access attribute and text values from elements in XPathResult?

Tags: javascript, dom

The following is all in JavaScript.

I have the following XML

```
<Hotels>
  <Hotel category='standard'>Hotel 1</Hotel>
  <Hotel category='superior'>Hotel 2</Hotel>
</Hotels>
```

My 'results' from my xpath ("//Hotel") returns an array with a length of 2.

What do I do next to get at the category values and the text.

i.e. `results[0].???? //will give me category value`

and `results[0].???? //will give me the text`

Comment: "Hotel 1 Hotel 2" doesn't look like XML. Also, which language are you using?

Comment: The result is a node set. So for each node @category will give you the category and text() will give you the text

Comment: They are just names of  hotels

Comment: I tried alert(results[0].@category) and alert(results[0].text()) and got blank alerts.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a single, one-liner XPath solution that selects all the required nodes. :)

Answer (score 0):

> my 'results' from my xpath ("//Hotel")
>   returns an array with a length of 2.
>
> what do I do next to get at the
>   category values and the text.

**You can select both the `category` attribute and the text child using a single XPath expression**:

```
/*/Hotel/@category | /*/Hotel/text()
```

The order of the results may depend on the XPath engine of use, but is usually document-order.

**So with the provided XML document**:

```
<Hotels>
    <Hotel category='standard'>Hotel 1</Hotel>
    <Hotel category='superior'>Hotel 2</Hotel>
</Hotels>
```

the above XPath expression selects four nodes: the `category` attribute of the 1st `Hotel` element, the text-node child of the 1st `Hotel` element, the `category` attribute of the 2nd `Hotel` element and the text-node child of the 2nd `Hotel` element

Comment: Thanks Dimitre but how do I get the values from those nodes?

Comment: @nexar: this depends on the particular XPath engine you are using. Usually the XPath expression is evaluated by calling a method called `SelectNodes()` and it returns a result of type often called `XmlNodeList`, so you have to iterate through the result to get to the individual `XmlNode` objects. You need to read your XPath/DOM documentation.

Comment: Also the other question I have is how do I know which of the 4 nodes returned relate to 'category' and which to text() or is that also something that is dependent on the particular XPath engine?

Comment: @nexar: Yes, usually the XmlNode object has a property that determines its node-type -- again, this may be different in different XPath implementations. But as I said, the nodes will most certainly be in document order, so in your case every `category` attribute will immediately precede its corresponding text node.

Comment: Yes you are right.  They are in document order and I am doing a switch statement on the nodeName to identify which node it is.  Thanks again for all your help.